# Showing that something is a Pushout

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, cw-complexes, diagram-chasing

Hoping to get a better understanding of CW complexes in terms of pushouts, I have decided to take a look at Jeffrey Strom's *Modern Classical Homotopy Theory* (truly wonderful title for a book, by the way), and I pretty much immediately manage to find myself dumbfounded. The question in particular is **Problem 3.1**:

> Let $i: S^{n-1} \rightarrow D^n$ be the inclusion of the boundary. (a) Show that the functions $j_N : x \mapsto (x, \sqrt{1-|x|^2})$ and $j_S : x \mapsto (x, - \sqrt{1-|x|^2})$ are homeomorphisms. (b) Show that the diagram (*) is a pushout square in the category **Top**.

The diagram being the following one.

[image: Picture from Jeffrey Strom's book]

Part (a) is no difficulty, but on part (b) I'm so hopelessly lost that I cannot even figure out where to begin!

Any and all help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you know the definition of a pushout?  Then check it.  Start with a space $Z$ and two compatible maps $D^{n+1} \to Z$....

Comment: It could also help to know what the $j$ maps are, intuitively. They are the inclusions of the northern and southern hemispheres, with overlap along the equator (the image of $S^n$).

Comment: Interesting point Arthur, perhaps if I explicitly $n=1$ first, then it will become easier.

Comment: ^Great point...

Comment: There are good modes for push outs in sets (and since the forgetful functor has a right adjoint, we know (basically) what pushouts should look like set theoretically. Google “adjunction space”

Answer (score 2):

The pushout of CW complexes (or most things in general) $X \xleftarrow{i} Z \xrightarrow{j} Y$ is a quotient of the disjoint union $X \coprod Y / \sim$ where $x \sim y$ if there is a $z \in Z$ such that $i(z) = j(z)$. CW complexes are closed under taking quotients so everything is fine here.

$j_S$ and $j_N$ map disks $D^{n+1}$ to the Southern (resp. Northern) "hemispheres" of $S^{n+1}$. Hence, the pushout is the disjoint union of two $D^{n+1}$ such that their equators are identified. This, of course, is just $S^{n+1}$.

To do this properly, you would want to show that $j_S \circ i = j_N \circ i$ and for any CW $W$ and maps $D^{n+1} \xrightarrow{j_N'} W$, $D^{n+1} \xrightarrow{j_S'} W$, that there is a unique $g: S^{n+1} \rightarrow W$. In some sense this is saying that the pushout $S^{n+1}$ is the largest object such that the diagram commutes.

By the way, $j_S$ and $j_N$ are not homeomorphisms. But, in any case they are homeomorphisms onto their images.